# Would Windows XP ever natively, without any third party programs,have a scratching/card shuffling noise that plays fairly randomly in the background?

Tags: windows-xp

Would Windows XP ever have a scratching/card shuffling noise that plays fairly randomly in the background?

And that's Windows XP doing so natively, so, even without any third party programs installed.

I think I did run into it at times.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can..

There is a question and answer on it here, that unfortunately got deleted by a moderator

https://superuser.com/questions/333880/what-is-the-source-of-this-funny-scratching-card-shuffling-noise-in-windows

In Windows XP when doing a search of files, there is/was an animation of a "dog" and the moment it scratched itself, there was a background noise of scratching.

[image]